# Which Oracle JDK supports Zip64?

Tags: java, zip

I found the following bug-report/enhancement that claims that JDK 7 b55 supports ZIP64: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4681995

Which official Oracle JDK-release corresponds to JDK 7 b55?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easy for all that follow to find the answer: *all* JDK7-releases by Oracle support ZIP64.

Comment: I have trying with jdk 1.7 and its giving this exception:
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 21504 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)